# Error in dynamically creating HTML component in lightning

Tags: lightning

I am creating a progress bar component
I am getting error

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'apply' of
>   undefined]

My component is :

```
<aura:component controller="OrgHealthAccessorController1" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="orgHealthAccessor" type="OrgHealthAccessor__c"/>
<aura:attribute name="message" type="Integer"/>    


    <head>
    <style>
        .meter { 
            height: 16px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #ebeef1;
            background-image: none;
        }
        .meter-bar { 
            float: left;
            width: 0;
            height: 100%;

            background-color: #4BCA81;
            background-image: none;
            box-shadow: none;

        }
        .bar-green {
            background-color: #4BCA81;
            background-image: none;
        }
        .bar-yellow {
            background-color: #F7B64B;
            background-image: none;
        }
        .bar-red {
            background-color: #ED6F67;
            background-image: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

    {!v.body}

</aura:component>
```

My Controller.js class  is

```
({
    doInit : function(component) {
            $A.createComponent(
               "aura:html",
                    { 
                        tag: "div",
                        HTMLAttributes:{"id": "green"},
                    }
                function(compo){
                      var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(compo);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }

            );
        }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This specific error was caused by invalid JavaScript in your controller; there is a missing comma between the second and third parameters of createComponent:

```
({
    doInit : function(component) {
            $A.createComponent(
               "aura:html",
                    { 
                        tag: "div",
                        HTMLAttributes:{"id": "green"},
                    }, // this comma was missing
                function(compo){
                      var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(compo);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }

            );
        }
})
```

---

As a side note, you shouldn't be putting a head element within a component. The styles should go within the style file of your component (Ctrl-Shift-4). Remember to use .THIS to scope your styles so they don't escape into the Lightning page itself, as it can cause undesirable interaction with the rest of the page.